# PHP if/elseif/else

Tags: php, if-statement

Can someone explain why this simple "ELSEIF" statement wont work:

```
<?php
if(strlen($_POST['word'])==null){
    echo "";
}
elseif(strlen($_POST['word']>5)){
    echo "This word has more than 5 letters";
}
else{
    echo "This word has less than 5 letters";
}

?>
```

"IF" is working OK and "ELSE" also works but when I type the word that has more than 5 letters it prints "This word has less than 5 letters" like in an "ELSE" statement.
Thank you

Comment: You condition is nonsense: `strlen($_POST['word']>5)`. Look again at your braces.

Comment: Additionally, the return value of `strlen()` is an integer, comparing it with NULL makes no sense.

Comment: @Sven That is not what the OP tried to do. It is a side effect of his glitch in the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You condition is nonsense: `strlen($_POST['word']>5)`. Look again at your braces.

Instead you probably mean this:

```
elseif(strlen($_POST['word'])>5){
```

No worries, such things happen to all of us :-)  Have fun!

Comment: oh well, thank you. I knew it was something simple and stupid. I'm struggling with PHP syntax...

Comment: An interesting statement, I take it as a compliment :-) I guess it is called experience.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
elseif(strlen($_POST['word']>5)){
```

To

```
elseif(strlen($_POST['word'])>5){
```